# Google Sheets Split / Trim From First Letter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of IDs like this :

```
40316C1
40316433D112
4316C1
4Z2 
40316B2
40310
```

I would like to return the IDs like this:

```
40316
40316433
4316
4
40316
40310
```

Basically, from the first alphabet Character, Trim or Split the rest on the right.

Can I do this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can do it with [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)

Sample:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d{1,20}")`

- This formula will evaluate the first 20 characters of the IDS (you can change `20` to ahigher number if necessary`
- `\d` means that the formula will extract only numbers from the IDs - until it finds the first non-number.

UPDATE:

The case of no text characters existing in the cell can be caught with [`=IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)

`=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A5,"\d{1,20}"),A5)+0`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ziganotschka. I forgot one case, which could be a full number like "40310". any workaround that? I want to return the number "40310"

Comment: Yes, easy workaround with `IFERROR` - just updated my answer.

Comment: Wicked! Thanks a lot!